# nvd3.js - Bigger points in a line chart

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am searching how to show bigger points in a line chart using nvd3.js, but I haven't found anything. Anybody can give me a hand?

I want the points to be easily visible across the chart lines.

Thanks.

Comment: I find those bubbles rather easily visible on hover: [nvd3 simple line chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/line.html).

Comment: @Sirko. Yes, but I would like to see bigger points by default, not inside the hover event. How do you know where are the points across the line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After looking through the output generated in the simple line chart, you could add this CSS, to make all points visible:

```
.nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point {
    stroke-opacity: 0.5 !important;
    stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

This is, however, more like a hack. There should be better solutions around. If you want to modify more details, it may also be better to switch to d3.js directly instead of using a wrapper.